# Select column from the same table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table, with 4 column: `id, name, to_id, to_id2`

```
SELECT id, name, (name WHERE to_id=id) as to1, (name WHERE to_id2=id) as to2 FROM table
```

I would like to show somehow the names instead of the to_id and to_id2. This code: `SELECT id, name, to_id, to_id2 FROM TABLE` give to_id, to_id2 as a number, because they are id-s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `JOIN`, try this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.name as t2Name, t3.name as t3Name
FROM tbl t1
LEFT JOIN tbl t2 ON t1.to_id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN tbl t3 ON t1.to_id2 = t3.id
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43e9c/5)

Answer (score 3):

Use `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END` :

```
SELECT id, name, 
(CASE WHEN to_id = id THEN name ELSE NULL END) as "t1",
(CASE WHEN to_id2 = id THEN name ELSE NULL END) as "t2"
FROM `your_table`
```

You can learn more about `case` statement [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html).